# How to debug a T-SQL trigger?

Tags: sql

I have a table t, which has an "after insert" trigger called trgInsAfter. Exactly how do i debug it? i'm no expert on this, so the question and steps performed might look silly.

The steps i performed so far are:
 1. connect to the `server instance` via `SSMS` (using a Windows Admin account)

1. right click the trigger node from the lefthand tree in SSMS and double click to open it, the code of the trigger is opened in a new query window (call this Window-1) as :  blah....,

   ```
   ALTER TRIGGER trgInsAfter AS .... BEGIN ... END
   ```
2. open another query window (call this Window-2), enter the sql to insert a row into table t:

   ```
   insert t(c1,c2) values(1,'aaa')
   ```
3. set a break point in Window-1 (in the trigger's code)
4. set a break point in Window-2 (the insert SQL code)
5. click the Debug button on the toolbar while Window-2 is the current window

   the insert SQL code's breakpoint is hit, but when I look at Window-1, the break point in the trigger's code has a tooltip saying `'unable to bind SQL breakpoint, object containing the breakpoint not loaded'`

I can sort of understand issue: how can `SSMS` know that the code in Window-1 is the trigger

I want to debug? i can't see where to tell SSMS that 'hey, the code in this query editor is table t's inssert trigger's code'

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: http://timwise.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/debugging-stored-procedures-in-vs2010.html

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You're actually over-thinking this.

I first run this query in one window (to set things up):

```
create table X(ID int not null)
create table Y(ID int not null)
go
create trigger T_X on X
after insert
as
    insert into Y(ID) select inserted.ID
go
```

I can then discard that window. I open a new query window, write:

```
insert into X(ID) values (1),(2)
```

And set a breakpoint on that line. I then *start* the debugger (`Debug` from menu or toolbar or Alt-F5) and wait (for a while, the debugger's never been too quick) for it to hit that breakpoint. And then, having hit there, I choose to `Step Into` (F11). And lo (after another little wait) a new window is opened which is my trigger, and the next line of code where the debugger stops is the `insert into Y...` line in the trigger. I can now set any further breakpoints I want to within the trigger.

Comment: Perfect, F11 did the trick!
Guess i've been working with C++/C# code for too long and got into the habit of loading all relevant source code files and pre-set breakpoints :(

Comment: Just want to add that in the automatically popped up window containing the trigger's source code, the path of it is formatted like this:

`mssql:://mywin7pc\bdsql/mydemodb/?/=338100245`


<windows servername>\<sql server instance>/<database name>/?/=id

Comment: Sadly, I am unable to see values in the virtual tables `inserted` and `deleted`

Comment: @Santhos - not just `inserted` and `deleted`. You'll find that there's no easy way to inspect any table contents whilst debugging. The debug experience is sorely lacking I'm afraid.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are completely correct. I have already decided to take a different approach, created a temp debug table and I am debugging in a very old school fashion using inserts, timestamps and some helper triggers.

Answer (score 4):

There is a DEBUG menu in SSMS, but you'll likely need to be on the server to be able to debug, so if it is a remote access, it's probably not gonna be set up for it.
That debug option will allow you to execute code, and step into your trigger and debug it in that manner (as you'd debug most any other code).

[image: Debug menu]

If not having access to the debug menu/function, you'll have to debug "manually":

First ensure your trigger is running correctly by inserting the input of the trigger into a debug table. Then you can verify that its called correctly.
Then you can debug the query of the trigger as you would any other sql query, using the values from the debug table.

Answer (score 1):

I also wasn't able to `Step Into`, it would go straight over my `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger. So I ended up replacing the trigger with:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [MyView_Instead_Insert] 
   ON  [MyView] 
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

select * into temp from INSERTED

END
```

Which created a table called temp with exaclty the column names and values of `INSERTED`.

Comment: you saved my day. I really appriciate your solution. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason I couldn't get @Damien_The_Unbeliever's solution to work.
At least, not on a trigger attached to a table. When I did a `Step Into` it just executed the query every time without stepping into the trigger.

Then I noticed in the comments of that approach that you can't see any of the table values anyway.

So......

I ended up creating a generic Debug Table.

```
USE [Your_DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Debug_Table](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [sql_variant] NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Captured] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

And then in my trigger I did something like this...

```
DECLARE @ItemNum nvarchar(128)
SELECT  @ItemNum = Item_Number FROM inserted

DECLARE @debugOn as bit = 1
-- Debug
    IF @debugOn = 1
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Debug_Table (Name, Value, Description, Captured)
        VALUES ( 'Item Number', @ItemNum, 'The item number from the inserted table in tr_VaultItemIterations_ZCode_Monitor.', GETDATE())
    END;
-- End Debug
```

After the trigger fired from the table I could view any of the variables I inserted to the Debug_Table.

After you're done debugging you could could easily turn off debugging inserts by changing the `@debugOn` variable to `0` in case you ever need to debug again in the future; or just remove the debug code altogether.