# SQL trigger to insert row in Table B if a column in Table A has certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger for when a user has a certain kind of email to put the user in correct security group. I have an if statement which checks their email but it seems like it's ignoring it.

```
      SET ANSI_NULLS ON
      GO
      SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
      GO
     ALTER TRIGGER [test].[UpdateSecurityGroup] ON  [test].[user]  

     AFTER INSERT AS begin 

     SET NOCOUNT ON;
     declare @insertedUseremail varchar; 
     select @insertedUseremail = inserted.email from inserted;    
     declare @insertedUserid int = 0;  
     select @insertedUserid = inserted.id from inserted;    

     if (@insertedUseremail like '%@test1.ca%' OR @insertedUseremail like '%@test2.ca%' OR @insertedUseremail like '%@test3.ca%' OR @insertedUseremail like '%@test4.ca%')  
     BEGIN    
     Insert into [test].[usergroup](userid,groupid) Values(@insertedUserid, 3)  
    END
    end
```

It inserts the user in the user table but does nothing in usergroup table.
It should insert in the rows in usergroup like this.

```
       +----+-----------+---------+
       | ID | userid    | groupid |
       +----+-----------+---------+
       |  1 | 001       |   3     |
       |  2 | 002       |   3     |
       |  3 | 003       |   3     |
       +----+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a critical mistake by assuming that `inserted` contains a single row.  No, no, no.  That is not the way to go.

```
alter trigger [test].[UpdateSecurityGroup] on  [test].[user] after insert as
begin 
     set nocount on;

    insert into [test].[usergroup](userid, groupid) 
        select i.id, 3
        from inserted i
        where i.email like '%@test1.ca%' OR
              i.email like '%@test2.ca%' OR 
              i.email like '%@test3.ca%' OR 
              i.email like '%@test4.ca%'
end;
```

If your emails really look like that, you can shorted the `where` to `where i.email like '%@test[1234].ca%`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what i was looking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your trigger.

Try this:

> [How to debug a T-SQL trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033109/how-to-debug-a-t-sql-trigger)
>
> 1. Create your trigger, and some test data in one window (to set things up)
> 2. Open a new query window, and type in your "insert".  Do *NOT* hit "Run" yet.
> 3. Set a breakpoint on that line
> 4. Start the debugger (Debug from menu or toolbar or Alt-F5)
> 5. Step into your trigger (F11)